# Pagina de agradecimiento con titulo de página anterior WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Hola chic@s mi duda es la siguiente.

Tenemos que hacer bastantes páginas de agradecimiento para inscripción a diferentes cursos, mi pregunta es 
¿Hay alguna manera de que por código se pueda rastrear el titulo de la página donde vienen y así solo hacer una página en general para todas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es solo cambiar lo que dice CQI-15 Evaluación..... (es el nombre del curso) por el titulo de la página donde viene.

Answer (score 0):

Al inscribirse en el curso podrías pasar un parámetro `GET` con el ID de la página des del que se realiza la inscripción, por ejemplo `http://web.com/gracias?id=12` y en la nueva página de 'Gracias' recuperar el parámetro de la URL `$id = $_GET['id'];` y llamar el link `$link = get_permalink($id);` y el título `$titulo = get_the_title($id);`.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu ayuda. No sé mucho de programación. ¿Donde debo insertar esto?